# Slow query using sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 with over 15 million rows and 49 columns. A simple query like this takes about 20 seconds to run. Is there any other ways to fine tune it? `Date_run` and `skid` are both indexed non clustered.

```
select skid, sum(price)
from stocktrack
where date_run >='2013-2-21'
  and date_run <='2013-3-21'
group by skid
```

Comment: Are skid and price included columns in the index that is indexed on date_run?  If you leave off the group by, how much faster is it?  Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: Those kind of queries are notoriously slow, because it can use the index on date_run only on one of the two clauses. If things go awry this index scan may still return all rows of the table. On Oracle you can force an "INDEX_ASC" scan, but I don't know whether there is an equivalent for sqlserver.

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg they are called [HINTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187713.aspx) on MSSQL Sever

Comment: How many rows does this return without the group by clause?  How much memory does the server have?  There are so many things that can impact performance.  We definitely need a lot more information to help.

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but the ideal index for this would be on date_run, including skid and price.  If you don't have that index and can build and test it, that may give you a quick answer.

Comment: It is funny, without summing, it added 1 more second and it returns 113409 rows. I guess there is no way to tune this up. My pc is intel i7 4770 3.4ghz and 12gb ram.

Comment: Show us how your table is defined and what indexes you have on it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I came here to say what @TonyHinkle said. That would be my first swing at tuning this query if that index isn't already defined as such. If it's possible, post an execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could reduce the amount of data to scan by partition the table on [date_run] column. It depends on the data variation in the column. You should get the execution plan before and after to check the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will try the partition method. Meanwhile I also found this cool heck. The query finished in 1 sec ...  select skid, sum(price)
from stocktrack WITH (NOLOCK)
where date_run >='2013-2-21'
and date_run <='2013-3-21'
group by skid